# UNIX: recursively paste a substring into the same string in unix

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, cut

My file is as follows:

```
$ cat a 
Server1 - free space: / 60% : /opt 40%: /var 50%    
Server2 - free space: / 50% : /opt 30%: /var 60%    
Server3 - free space: / 30% : /opt 50%: /var 40%
```

The output is to be written to another file b. My expected output would be as follows:

```
$ cat b
Server1 - free space: / 60% 
Server1 - free space: /opt 40%
Server1 - free space: /var 50%
Server2 - free space: / 50% 
Server2 - free space: /opt 30%
Server2 - free space: /var 60%
Server3 - free space: / 30% 
Server3 - free space: /opt 50%
Server3 - free space: /var 40%
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$ awk -F' *: *' -v OFS=': ' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $i}' file 
Server1 - free space: / 60%
Server1 - free space: /opt 40%
Server1 - free space: /var 50%
Server2 - free space: / 50%
Server2 - free space: /opt 30%
Server2 - free space: /var 60%
Server3 - free space: / 30%
Server3 - free space: /opt 50%
Server3 - free space: /var 40%
```

Answer (score 1):

For this case you need to separate your "subject" text from your data.

With awk you get this for free, since it parses each input line, and places each field into numbered variables - $1, $2, etc.
You also get the actual number of fields - NF - for each line for free, calculated by awk

Given this, you can start off with

```
awk '{ print $1, $2 }' a

Output: Server1 -
```

Not completely what you want.

You *could* keep counting manually, or even just hard code some of your text:

```
awk '{ Subject=$1" "$2" "$3" "$4 ; print Subject, $5, $6, "\n" Subject, $8, $9, "\n" Subject, $10, $11 }' b
```

Allthough, this prints your output, it's not very elegant. However, you get a feel with fields.

When awk splits a line into fields, i does so by saying that one field is any field surrounded by whitespace, i.e. , .
You can change what awk uses as it's field separator by using the command line parameter "-F" or setting it explicitly in a BEGIN block.

The BEGIN block is run *once* before awk even looks at the file.

So then you can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } { print $1, $2 }' a

Output: Server1 - free space  / 60%
```

So you are getting closer, but you also want a semicolon before your output, so you do:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" } { print $1 ":", $2 }' a

# Or, by setting OFS - the Output Field Separator
awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" ; OFS=":" } { print $1,$2 }' a

Output: Server1 - free space: / 60%
```

You still only get one filesystem in your output, so you need to reference those too, which can be done directly, if you are sure you always will have only three filesystems in your input:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" ; OFS=":" } { print $1,$2 "\n" $1, $3 "\n" $1, $4 }' a

Server1 - free space: / 60%
Server1 - free space: /opt 40%
Server1 - free space: /var 50%
```

But what you want is a loop which gives you flexibility with regards to the number of filesystems/fields you encounter, where you get to Ed Morton's answer, where I've just moved the declaration of FS (field separator) and OFS (output field separator) to the BEGIN block:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" ; OFS=":" } {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1, $i}' a > b
$ cat b
Server1 - free space: / 60%
Server1 - free space: /opt 40%
Server1 - free space: /var 50%
Server2 - free space: / 50%
Server2 - free space: /opt 30%
Server2 - free space: /var 60%
Server3 - free space: / 30%
Server3 - free space: /opt 50%
Server3 - free space: /var 40%
```

You also have an END block, which is run *after* all lines are parsed:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=":" ; OFS=":" }
    {servers++ ; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { print $1, $i ; sum++ } }
    END { printf("\nParsed %i lines producing %i lines\n", servers, sum) }' a
Server1 - free space: / 60%
Server1 - free space: /opt 40%
Server1 - free space: /var 50%
Server2 - free space: / 50%
Server2 - free space: /opt 30%
Server2 - free space: /var 60%
Server3 - free space: / 30%
Server3 - free space: /opt 50%
Server3 - free space: /var 40%

Parsed 3 lines producing 9 lines
```